# High value of shm_flushes in Varnish 3.0.5

Tags: varnish

We've a very hight value of shm_flushes in varnishstat:

```
Hitrate ratio:        0        0        0
Hitrate avg:     0.0000   0.0000   0.0000

     3900996        90.85          inf backend_busy - Backend conn. too many
    12498808       228.62          inf backend_reuse - Backend conn. reuses
     9950893       186.69          inf backend_toolate - Backend conn. was closed
       35649         0.00          inf backend_recycle - Backend conn. recycles
      733236        10.98          inf backend_retry - Backend conn. retry
       94911         0.00          inf fetch_head - Fetch head
         468         0.00          inf fetch_eof - Fetch EOF
     1962214        25.96          inf fetch_bad - Fetch had bad headers
       16922         0.00          inf fetch_close - Fetch wanted close
     1979182        34.94          inf fetch_oldhttp - Fetch pre HTTP/1.1 closed
          26         0.00          inf fetch_zero - Fetch zero len
         927         0.00          inf fetch_failed - Fetch failed
     1260014        29.95          inf fetch_1xx - Fetch no body (1xx)
      332729         5.99          inf fetch_204 - Fetch no body (204)
        7341          .            .   n_sess - N struct sess
         112          .            .   n_objectcore - N struct objectcore
      456054          .            .   n_vbc - N struct vbc
         762          .            .   n_wrk - N worker threads
         427       -40.93          inf n_wrk_create - N worker threads created
      368860        -2.00          inf n_wrk_failed - N worker threads not created
      368974         2.00          inf n_wrk_lqueue - work request queue length
      361762        11.98          inf n_wrk_queued - N queued work requests
         115         0.00          inf n_wrk_drop - N dropped work requests
          42          .            .   n_backend - N backends
         115          .            .   n_expired - N expired objects
        2747          .            .   n_lru_nuked - N LRU nuked objects
       18073         0.00          inf n_objwrite - Objects sent with write
          14         0.00          inf s_sess - Total Sessions
      364370        12.98          inf s_req - Total Requests
     7843107       119.80          inf s_pass - Total pass
     9802175       187.68          inf s_bodybytes - Total body bytes
     3900985       108.82          inf sess_pipeline - Session Pipeline
    12498808       228.62          inf sess_readahead - Session Read Ahead
           6         0.00          inf sess_linger - Session Linger
     1323887        26.95          inf sess_herd - Session herd
     2056953        37.94          inf shm_records - SHM records
  4873964594     91989.09          inf shm_writes - SHM writes
304821503001   6421550.43          inf shm_flushes - SHM flushes due to overflow
     1057284        31.95          inf shm_cont - SHM MTX contention
         102         0.00          inf shm_cycles - SHM cycles through buffer
          94         0.00          inf sms_nreq - SMS allocator requests
    11853499          .            .   sms_nobj - SMS outstanding allocations
    10496270          .            .   sms_nbytes - SMS outstanding bytes
   655590062          .            .   sms_balloc - SMS bytes allocated
    38937693          .            .   sms_bfree - SMS bytes freed
      211416         2.00          inf n_vcl - N vcl total
         302         0.00          inf n_vcl_avail - N vcl available
       24886         0.00          inf n_vcl_discard - N vcl discarded
    10704338         0.00          inf n_ban_add - N new bans added
    10704338         0.00          inf n_ban_retire - N old bans deleted
     2057082        25.96          inf n_ban_obj_test - N objects tested
           3         0.00          inf n_ban_re_test - N regexps tested against
           3         0.00          inf n_ban_dups - N duplicate bans removed
           2         0.00          inf hcb_lock - HCB Lookups with lock
           1         0.00          inf hcb_insert - HCB Inserts
           2         0.00          inf esi_errors - ESI parse errors (unlock)
         535         0.00          inf accept_fail - Accept failures
         535         0.00          inf client_drop_late - Connection dropped late
    10718794       175.70          inf dir_dns_lookups - DNS director lookups
      610318         4.99          inf dir_dns_failed - DNS director failed lookups
      610316         4.99          inf dir_dns_hit - DNS director cached lookups hit
```

also the hitrate is shown 0, but we have definitely cache hits in Varnish as we can see in the responses and varnishlog

We tried -p shm_workspace=16384 in DAEMON_OPTS but shm_flushes still increasing.

Shouldn't be the value of shm_flushes nearly 0?

Answer (score 1):

This listing/output doesn't make sense.

shm_flushes should be in the same order as shm_records. 6.4 million per second clearly isn't.

I suspect you're using the wrong version of libvarnishapi.

Comment: How we can check the version of libvarnishapi?

Comment: There is libvarnishapi.so -> libvarnishapi.so.1.0.0 in /usr/local/lib. But which one is needed for Varnish 3.0.5? The sysadmins recently updated from 3.0.3 to 3.0.5, maybe they corrupted the installation.

Comment: You need libvarnishapi to be the same version as varnishd. How to verify is dependent on how you install varnish. dpkg -l will tell you on debian/ubuntu systems.

Comment: The libvarnishapi was in wrong version, we updated with apt-get install --reinstall libvarnishapi1, but still shm_flushes are a multiple (x 40k) of shm_records.

Answer (score 1):

I would be more concerned about *inf backend_busy - Backend conn. too many* in the first place. And also that you Hitrate ratio is 0 0 0.

I had similar problem with stats not reporting correctly: for some reason I had libvarnishapi-dev instead of libvarnishapi1 lib installed and also probably the wrong version.

After I did `sudo app-install libvarnishapi1` and reboot I don't get *backend_busy - Backend conn. too many* any more and my clocks are also ticking now in `varnishstat`.

When you get there, see if you shm_flushes are still too high.

Comment: we soon did a sudo apt-get install --reinstall libvarnishapi1, without any effect. I think rebooting the machine would make no sense at all.

Comment: Ran the update for libvarnishapi and it fixed the issue, no restart required. This was on Debian Wheezy